# Why in response the data of different table coming in different array?(using Django, Rest framework, MySql)

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Actually I have joined various tables in Django using Rest framework and MySql database. The response is coming correctly but data from different table is coming in different arrays. But I want the response in a single array.I am posting the present response and the required response. Please help me out with this.

The response is coming like this :

```
{
"count": 282566,
"next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/inventoryregister/?limit=1000&offset=1000",
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "inventory_batch": {
            "inventory_reg": {
                "id": 77,
                "company_id": "2",
                "inventory_group_id": "39",
                "product_id": "834",
                "is_owned": "1",
                "cost_center": {
                    "location": "123123213",
                    "lob_id": 87,
                    "department_id": 470,
                    "cs_id": "117",
                    "nick_name": "123123213",
                    "lob": {
                        "lob_name": "ssss",
                        "lob_nick_name": "ssss",
                        "cs_id": "0"
                    },
                    "department": {
                        "department_name": "test dept6545",
                        "department_nick_name": "test dept6",
                        "cs_id": "44"
                    }
                },
                "inventory_date": "2019-04-24",
                "inventory_action": "2",
                "stock_qty": "100.0",
                "price_per_unit": "1000.0",
                "total_price": "100000.0",
                "status": "1",
                "added_by": "3254",
                "updated_by": "3254",
                "date_added": "2019-04-20 00:26:37",
                "date_updated": "2019-04-20 00:27:57",
                "product_type2_id": "6",
                "asset_type": {
                    "asset_type": "Fixed Assets"
                },
                "dimension": null
            },
            "batch_no": "PRO2175200420192"
        },
        "barcode_no": "0397622466"
    }
```

But I want the response in this way :

```
{
"count": 282566,
"next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/inventoryregister/?limit=1000&offset=1000",
"previous": null,
"results": [
              {
                "id": 77,
                "company_id": "2",
                "inventory_group_id": "39",
                "product_id": "834",
                "is_owned": "1",
                "location": "123123213",
                "lob_id": 87,
                "department_id": 470,
                "cs_id": "117",
                "nick_name": "123123213",
                "lob_name": "ssss",
                "lob_nick_name": "ssss",
                "cs_id": "0"
                "department_name": "test dept6545",
                "department_nick_name": "test dept6",
                "cs_id": "44"
                "inventory_date": "2019-04-24",
                "inventory_action": "2",
                "stock_qty": "100.0",
                "price_per_unit": "1000.0",
                "total_price": "100000.0",
                "status": "1",
                "added_by": "3254",
                "updated_by": "3254",
                "date_added": "2019-04-20 00:26:37",
                "date_updated": "2019-04-20 00:27:57",
                "product_type2_id": "6",
                "asset_type": "Fixed Assets"
                "dimension": null
                "batch_no": "PRO2175200420192"
                "barcode_no": "0397622466"
              }
           }
```

And this is my code :

view.py

```
def index(request):

 if request.method=='GET':  

   all_dataobj=inventory_bar_codes.
   objects.all().select_related("inventory_batch)

   paginator = CustomPagination()
   result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(all_dataobj, request)

   pserializer=inventory_bar_codesSerializers(result_page,many=True)

   return paginator.get_paginated_response(pserializer.data)
```

serializer.py

```
class asset_typeSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:

   model = asset_type
   fields = ['asset_type']

class department_detailsSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:

   model = department_details
   fields = ['department_name','department_nick_name','cs_id']

class lobSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:

    model = lob
    fields = ['lob_name','lob_nick_name','cs_id']

class dimensionsSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:

    model = dimensions
    fields = ['dimension_code','dimension_name']

class locationsSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

 lob = lobSerializers(read_only=True)
 department = department_detailsSerializers(read_only=True)

 class Meta: 

   model = locations
   fields = ['location','lob_id','department_id',
             'cs_id','nick_name','lob','department']  

 class inventoryregisterSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  cost_center = locationsSerializers(read_only=True)
  dimension = dimensionsSerializers(read_only=True)
  asset_type = asset_typeSerializers(read_only=True)

  class Meta:

    model = inventoryregister
    fields = ['id','company_id','inventory_group_id','product_id',
             'is_owned','cost_center','inventory_date','inventory_action',
             'stock_qty','price_per_unit','total_price',
             'status','added_by','updated_by',
             'date_added','date_updated','product_type2_id',
             'asset_type','cost_center','dimension','asset_type']

class inventory_batchSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  inventory_reg = inventoryregisterSerializers(read_only=True)

  class Meta:

    model = inventory_batch
    fields = ['inventory_reg','batch_no'] 

class inventory_bar_codesSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  inventory_batch = inventory_batchSerializers(read_only=True)

  class Meta:

    model = inventory_bar_codes
    fields = ['inventory_batch','barcode_no']
```

model.py

```
 class asset_type(models.Model):

   id = models.IntegerField
   company_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   asset_type = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   status = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   added_by = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   date_added = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   date_updated = models.CharField(max_length=250)

     class Meta:

       db_table = 'asset_type'

class department_details(models.Model):

 id = models.IntegerField
 department_code = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 company_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 costcenter_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 department_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 department_nick_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 dept_start_date = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 added_by = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 status = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 date_added = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 date_updated = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 cs_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 logistic_dept = models.CharField(max_length=250)

   class Meta:

     db_table = 'department_details'

class lob(models.Model):

 id = models.IntegerField
 lob_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 company_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 client_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 logo = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 lob_brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 lob_start_date = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 lob_nick_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 added_by = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 date_added = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 date_updated = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 status = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 lob_status = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 cs_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)

   class Meta:

     db_table = 'lob'

class dimensions(models.Model):

 id = models.IntegerField
 company_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 client_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 dimension_code = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 dimension_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 dimension_type = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 country = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 state = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 city = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 location = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 pincode = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 furnishing_status = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 status = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 added_by = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 date_added = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 date_updated = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 cs_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 is_this_warehouse = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 representative_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 representative_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 representative_email = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 rack_dimension = models.CharField(max_length=250)

   class Meta:

    db_table = 'dimensions'

class locations(models.Model):

 id = models.IntegerField
 cs_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 company_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 client_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 lob = models.ForeignKey(lob,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 location = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 nick_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 gst_no = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 state = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 city = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 pincode = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 status = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 added_by = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 date_added = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 date_updated = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 start_date = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 is_lob_mapped = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 is_department_mapped = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 department = models.ForeignKey(department_details,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 is_dimension_mapped = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 dimension_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 is_sez = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 is_eou = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 location_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)

  class Meta:

    db_table = 'locations'

class inventoryregister(models.Model): 

 id = models.IntegerField
 company_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 inventory_group_id = models.CharField(max_length=15)
 product_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 is_owned = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 asset_type = models.ForeignKey(asset_type,db_column='asset_type',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 cost_center = models.ForeignKey(locations,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 inventory_date = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 inventory_action = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 stock_qty = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 price_per_unit = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 total_price = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 status = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 added_by = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 date_added = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 date_updated = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 product_type2_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 dimension = models.ForeignKey(dimensions,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   class Meta:

     db_table = 'inventory_register'

class inventory_batch(models.Model):

 id = models.IntegerField
 company_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 inventory_reg = models.ForeignKey(inventoryregister,
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 batch_no = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 status = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 added_by = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 date_added = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 date_updated = models.CharField(max_length=250)

 class Meta:

   db_table = 'inventory_batch'

class inventory_bar_codes(models.Model):

 id = models.IntegerField
 company_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 inventory_reg_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 inventory_batch = models.ForeignKey(inventory_batch,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 barcode_no = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 status = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 is_available = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 qrcode_file = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 added_by = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 date_added = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 date_updated = models.CharField(max_length=250)

  class Meta:

   db_table = 'inventory_bar_codes'
```

Comment: plz add your view and serializer

Comment: I have updated the question with my model.py view.py and serializer.py.....please help me by some solution...@c.grey

Comment: I have added model.py view.py and serializer.py.....please help me by some solution...@Anjaneyulu Batta

Comment: Your serializers are each creating their own keys. If you create a custom serializer that doesn't inherit from ModelSerializer, then you can structure the data any way you like.

Comment: I understood little bit ... but can you please elaborate and show examples....thank you...@Dov Rine

Comment: anybody please help me out with this....I am stuck for so long...